npm run build for vite project not working Error: Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type
After building the vite project using npm run build,
the compiled/built html code does not contain correct path.
However the same project when run through npm run dev runs perfectly and the issue occurs only when I build the project.
You can clone the project and build it: GitHub Repo
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-DVoHNO1Y.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-DiwrgTda.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

it misses . before the path
href="/vite.svg" / instead of href="./vite.svg" / which works when i edit the html file.
Is there any way to fix this?
It causes error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with index-DVoHNO1Y.js:1
a status of 404 (Not Found)
Refused to apply style from
index.html:1
http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/index-DiwrgIda.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
Live reload enabled.
index.html: 41
Refused to apply style from '
index.html:1
http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/index-DiwrgIda.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I have tried this with create-react-app and the result is the same. The issue could be from my development environment.
Please take a note that I did not change the code after initializing the project.
